# Building/constructing buildings at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm playing around with an FPS where I want my player(s) to be able to build/construct their own buildings from scratch. I've searched around for exisiting solutions/theories, but have so far been unable to find anything suitable to my needs. Please point me in the right direction if I've missed anything.

Where I am right now is that I have three prefabs; floor, wall and wall with a door opening. First I want to instantiate floor tiles which I then can put walls on, and hopefully being able to have the walls snap to the edges/corners of the floor tiles.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction for how to do this? Also, does my desired "work flow" at all make sense? Any pitfalls in there?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** Here's what I have in regards to instantiation prefabs, and while this works (except it's like I'm shooting walls), I would like the wall to snap to the corners/edges of the nearest floor (which has already been instantiated in the same fashion.

```cs
[RequireComponent (typeof (CharacterController))]
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

// Declare prefabs here
GameObject wallPrefab;

// Initialise variables before the game starts
void Awake () {
    wallPrefab = (GameObject)Resources.Load( "WoodWall" );
}

// This happens every frame
void Update () {

    if ( Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") ) {
        // Instantiate new wall
        Instantiate( wallPrefab, cc.transform.position + cc.transform.forward + Vector3.up * 1.0f, wallPrefab.transform.rotation );
    }

}
```

}

Comment: So what exactly are you stuck on? You obviously know about prefabs and you seem to know how to [Instantiate](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html).

Comment: I added the code I have at the moment. I'm not sure why the top/bottom isn't part of the syntax highlighting, though...

Answer (score 0):

hmm... well one solution I can think of, is to have the wall raycast downwards in order to find a floor, then move to a predetermined position in relation to that floor (if it found any). Stick this in a script in the wall prefabs:

```
void Start()
{
    var down = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.down); //down might not actually be the down direction of your object, check to make sure
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, down, out hit) && hit.collider.gameObject.name == "myFloorName")  //Maybe use tags here instead of name
    {
        Vector3 floorPos = hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position;
        Vector3 floorSize = hit.collider.gameObject.transform.localScale;
        this.transform.position = new Vector3(floorPos.x - floorSize.x/2, floorPos.y - this.tranform.localScale.y/2, floorPos.z); //These might need fiddling with to get right
    }
}

void Update()
{
}
```

Vector3.down may not correspond to the down direction for the wall, since this can depend on the 3d model too, so you might need to fiddle with that. The position might also need fiddling with (this assumes that y corresponds to height, which might not be the case), but hopefully this gives you a rough idea of how it can be done. Also, if you don't know what the name of the floor object is, you could probably check by tags, which is probably easier.

If anything else needs clarifying, leave a comment and I'll get back to you

Comment: I will try this when I get home from work. I the meantime, would you like to enlighten me in terms of how to manage my controllers properly? In this case, would it make sense to put all this building functionality into a ConstructionController and have that attached to the user, or are there other - and better - ways to organize it?

Comment: In this case, the script above would go into the wall prefabs. It runs some code once when its instantiated, and shouldn't need to run again afterwards. As far as the stuff attached to the user, separate it into what makes sense to you. For example, having all user related construction in a script on the user, means you won't need to go hunting later to find where that one line of code is (something that I've had to do... and it's not fun :P)

Comment: This didn't make much of a difference to what I already had, but I now understand a bit more how things work. Still not sure how to snap to another object's corners, though.

Comment: I found a way to easily (...) debug this whole thing while I'm placing a object by setting the object to the child of the camera, then I can move it around before setting it down. That way I can Debug.Log all kinds of x/y/z positions while trying to figure this out. :) Thanks for all your help, and please feel free to add on any hints or tips.